# Timeout result if nothing returns from started process - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

`functionB` starts `functionA`. How can I say if no results com back from 
functionA in let's say 5 seconds return "Nothing returned" from `functionB` and kill `functionA` process

```
def functionA():
    value1 = open()
    if (value1 != None):
        value2 = testcolor()
        return value2
    else:
        value3 = close()
        return value3


def functionB():
    thread = multiprocessing.Process(name='send_daemon%d', target=functionA)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    res = {'status': 'started' ,}
    return json.dumps(res)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) class has a timeout, and I would suggest using that:

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue

def functionA(return_queue):
    value1 = open()
    if (value1 != None):
        value2 = testcolor()
        return_queue.put(value2)
    else:
        value3 = close()
        return_queue.put(value3)


def functionB():

    return_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(
        name='send_daemon%d', target=functionA, args=(return_queue,))
    proc.daemon = True
    proc.start()
    res = {'status': 'started' ,}

    try:
        # wait for two seconds for the function to return a value
        return_value = return_queue.get(timeout=2)
    except Queue.Empty:
        proc.terminate()
        return_value = None

    # do something with the return value here

    return json.dumps(res)
```

Notes:

1. Don't confuse the multprocessing library with the threading library. `multiprocessing.Process()` starts a new *process*, not a *thread*, so you should name your variables appropriately.
2. In your code, you haven't shown exactly how you intended to retrieve or use the return value from the second process. As far as I know, there is no way to retrieve the return value of a `multiprocessing.Process()`. This queue implementation will allow you to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

In your case when function a ends - it will merely stop itself, there is no need to do anything further.

But if you need to shutdown a running process. The two easiest choices are: 
Start functionA with a `multiprocessing.Event` and have it shutdown if the event is set.

Otherwise you can use a signal (this is accessible vis `Process().terminate`) - before you do that you should probably read this: 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/librar/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process

Especially:

> Warning
>   If this method is used when the associated process is using a pipe or
>   queue then the pipe or queue is liable to become corrupted and may
>   become unusable by other process. Similarly, if the process has
>   acquired a lock or semaphore etc. then terminating it is liable to
>   cause other processes to deadlock.

Comment: Thanks. In my application if user doesn't press a button function a doesn't end and I will get "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))" message.

Comment: I can't help with arbitrary applications, only with the code you post in your question.